# Set query criteria with form check box

Tags: ms-access

I have a table "MyTable"

```
Id Color
1  blue
2  Red
```

And a query "Myquery"

```
Id  Color  Car
1  Red     BMW
2  Blue    BMW
3  Green   BMW
4  Yellow  Merc
5  Red     Alpha
```

and I have a form "MyForm" with a check box "check box 1".
I would like to set "MyQuery" criteria with "MyForm" base on "MyTable" (color). If "check box 1" is checked, the criteria as mention has been set. 
The result suppose shown, "BMW BMW Alpha".
How and where to set that?

Here my SQL,

```
SELECT tblSourceB.KODPST, tblSourceB.KODSEK
FROM (tblSourceB LEFT JOIN MyTable ON tblSourceB.KODSEK = MyTable.KodSekFLd);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the AfterUpdate event of the checkbox, you can do something like

```vb
If Me!CheckBox1 = True Then
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter WhereCondition:="Color IN (SELECT Color FROM MyTable)"
Else
    ' Turn filter off
    DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
End If
```

Or if you want to change `MyQuery`, post its SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's just filtered the Form not the Query it self.